# Display last 7 business days

Tags: sql-server

```
WHERE   
        u.id = 73
        AND 
        cast(reading_time as date) BETWEEN DATEADD(day,-8, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

How Can I get only the last 7 business days ?

Comment: provide sample data and desire output. And what you mean business days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (**TL;DR**):

```
WHERE
    CAST(READING_TIME AS DATE) BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -8, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE())
    AND DATEPART(DW, CAST(READING_TIME AS DATE)) IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

---

**Update:**

Here is a more comprehensive script which will help you extract the correct business days from your data. Depending on where you live, business days can be either `Monday-Friday` or `Sunday-Thursday` and possibly others (I don't know of others).

```
DECLARE @TEST TABLE(READING_TIME DATETIME);

INSERT INTO @TEST VALUES('12-JAN-2016');
INSERT INTO @TEST VALUES('11-JAN-2016');
INSERT INTO @TEST VALUES('10-JAN-2016');
INSERT INTO @TEST VALUES('9-JAN-2016');
INSERT INTO @TEST VALUES('8-JAN-2016');
INSERT INTO @TEST VALUES('7-JAN-2016');
INSERT INTO @TEST VALUES('6-JAN-2016');
INSERT INTO @TEST VALUES('5-JAN-2016');
INSERT INTO @TEST VALUES('4-JAN-2016');
INSERT INTO @TEST VALUES('3-JAN-2016');
INSERT INTO @TEST VALUES('2-JAN-2016');
INSERT INTO @TEST VALUES('1-JAN-2016');

DECLARE @TO_DATE DATE;

SET @TO_DATE = '12-JAN-2016';

-- SET DATEFIRST 1;

SELECT
    READING_TIME
    , DATEPART(DW, READING_TIME) AS [Day of the week]
    , DATENAME(DW, READING_TIME) AS [Day of the week - name]
FROM @TEST
WHERE CAST(READING_TIME AS DATE) BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -8, @TO_DATE) AND @TO_DATE
    AND DATEPART(DW, CAST(READING_TIME AS DATE)) IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

The `"Day of the week - name"` column from my script will help you understand and make sure that you get the correct weekdays which are also business days in your context.

I've also added a `SET DATEFIRST 1` command which will set the first date of the week as Monday, in case your system has it otherwise (but only for the purpose of running this script).

Based on the value of this variable, the values in the `"Day of week"` will change and you will obviously have to change the values in the `WHERE` clause.

Hope all of this is clear.